# Be $G$ a group with $ | G | = 6^n$, show that there is normal subgroup of order $3 ^ n$ or $3 ^ {n-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to show that there are 2 3-sylows such that the intersection between them has order 3 ^ (n-1), and then I already know how to do the rest, but I can not quite show this fact.

Comment: The statement in the title is false. For example there exists a group of order $6^4$ with no normal subgroup of order $3^4$ or $3^3$.

Answer (score 1):

First, the question in the title does not match the question in the body. The question in the title can be answered using Sylow's Theorem. As for the question in the body, it is wrong as currently stated. For example, the Sylow $3$-subgroup might be normal, in which case it is unique, and you will not be able to find two such with intersection of index 3.

Comment: I found that I got results (solving problems) solving the problem, but it's already false, or it just does not, how to do it then?

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten the word that defines the problem, normal subgroup.